# how to save GTFS data into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, python

I have downloaded some GTFS data from http://www.131500.com. It is a zip file containing some text files such as `stops.txt`, `trips.txt` etc.

Now I would like to save that data in an SQLite database but am not sure how to do so. I did download GTFSImporter from https://github.com/jvashishtha/GTFSImporter/tree/master/GTFSImporter but I am not sure how to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on what you want to do with it.

I've done it two ways - the simple way, and the more complex way.

The simple way is to load the data in directly column for column, row for row. Like this:

http://oegeo.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/salt-lake-city-gtfs-into-sqlite/

The more complex way is to use Graphserver and its "GTFSDB", which I think is really just an sqlite db.

http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver/

I've done both of these procedures with 131500's data before.

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, but what's the advantage of using graphserver?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fast 2 command line method.  Install querycsv with your favorite python installer (`sudo pip install querycsv` will work).  Then to create a sqlite file named db.sqlite run

```
querycsv.py -i routes.txt -i trips.txt -f db.sqlite -k "select * from routes limit 1"
```

Add as many of the gtfs tables as you need with more `-i <table>.txt` arguments.  (The sql statement there is a little oddball, any legal sql statement will work, you aren't selecting what is imported. You do need a no op statement though.)

The tables will get the filenames of the csv files and the header rows will import as the table column names automatically.