# Android Studio Public Transit app - GTFS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gtfs

I am currently working on a project that would show a static page of a tram stop, and that page would show departure times of different trams.

I found GTFS files of my local public transit company, but I don't really know how to incorporate them into my project.

The only thing I need to get from those files are departure times.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to do all of this on the device itself?

Comment: Hi @TonyLaidig. Yes, I am planning to have an Android powered tablet, that would show a page with tram number, time of arrival and time left. It would be an offline app, meaning that I would probably need an SQLite database somehow incorporated in the app that would show the info from the GTFS files that I found. I am still a beginner, so I might not understand how to make this properly.

Comment: Edit: I don't want to add data during runtime, like this app from Udacity here: https://github.com/udacity/ud845-Pets/tree/lesson-four , I want to load the database I already have to display the info in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving GTFS data into an `SQLite database`. Use the SQLite database for accessing the details.

For saving GTFS data into SQLite database check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135811/how-to-save-gtfs-data-into-sqlite-database)

Comment: Thanks for the help.